# Linear regression: residual values do not have zero mean

Tags: linear-regression

I performed a linear regression model `y~x` in R by running

```
lr <- lm (y~x, data = train)
p <- predict (lr, newdata = test)
error <- p - test$y
```

It seems that `error` does not have zero mean (in fact, `mean(error) = -5`), it is right-skewed and I could not say it belongs to any kind of distribution I know.

Furthermore, I tried to replace `lm` with `rlm(MASS)`, but the RMSE and MAE of the prediction does not increase.

What is some alternative approaches to explore in this situation? I am thinking of a problem that error term (`\epsilon`) is not independence from `x`, but not sure how to model that?

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess... Maybe your y could have a non-linear dependence on x, which could explain the skewed residuals?

Comment: in this case, the linear relation is provided, i.e. it has to be a linear regression to be performed.